# Angular JS - Ng-Repeat issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am defining my array as shown:

```
$scope.tt=  [
  {
    "name" : "1",
    "sel" : false
  },
  {
    "name" : "2",
    "sel" : false
  },
  {
    "name" : "3",
    "sel" : false
  }
];
```

And showing in my view as so:

```
<div ng-repeat="mod in tt" ng- class="t text-center">
    <img src="images/tt/{{mod.name}}.png"/>
    <span class="tt">{{mod.name}}</span>

    <div class="overlay" ng-show="mod.sel">

      <div class="range-slider" data-slider data-options="start: 1; end: 10;">
        <span class="range-slider-handle" role="slider" tabindex="0"></span>
        <span class="range-slider-active-segment"></span>
        <input type="hidden">
      </div>

      <button>Ok</button>
      <button>Cancel</button>
    </div>


</div>
```

It works and shows all three of my items name and the related image but then errors:

GET http://localhost:63342/tt/images/tt/%7B%7Bmod.name%7D%7D.png 404 (Not Found)

As if there is 4 items rather than 3?

What could cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is happening because your src is being loaded by the browser before angular kicks in and interpolates the variable. This means that the`{{mod.name}}` is being interpreted literally and results in the URL that 404s when you try to load it.

You should use ng-src instead. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Answer (score 2):

You should be seeing about 3 errors, one per item.

The reason is that you use `src` instead of `ng-src`, hence the browser immediately tries to fetch the image. Change to:

```
<img ng-src="images/tt/{{mod.name}}.png"/>
```